# Likelihood ratio test MLE Question

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

[image]

For working out and maximizing the MLE of the general case, how do you work out the MLE for theta?

I can work out the MLE for beta when theta isn't 0. Is the MLE for theta obtained when theta = mean of xi? However, this causes my MLE for beta to = 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No MLE of theta is not mean of Xi . But it is MinXi because likelihood function is increasing function of theta and theta is maximum at Min Xi . so MLE of theta is MinXi. 
So MLE for beta is( summation Xi-nMinXi)/n